# How to Test JSP and Servlets in a Testing machine?

Tags: testing

I am new to Java web Technology, I wanted to configure a server and Testing the Jsp and servlets application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download a server installer (a Tomcat would be the best), run it, and then, after the installation is complete, open your IDE (Eclipse, I presume), look for the "Servers" perspective, and right-click on it. There you can create a new server.

For further reading, http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html